# Avoiding zIndex by appending dom elements

Tags: javascript, performance, dom, z-index, reflow

So I'm trying to control the stacking of equally-sized  elements via z-index. 
Now an idea that I came across recently to avoid going through z-indices and improve performance times by hopefully to avoiding browser reflows is instead order layers via the order I append things to the parent.

So if I have a container div that holds all the stacking divs, and linked list that mirrors the order, referencing the stacking divs, then I reorder the divs based on user input. Then instead of updating the z-indices, I would recreate the div element and just append everything in order. So something like this:

```
var from = nodeBeforeFrom; // Input
var target = nodeBeforeTarget; // Input
var linkedlist = input; // var linkedlist contains all the stacking divs
linkedlist.moveElement(div1, div2); //Move div1 to after div2
var container = document.createElement('div');

linkedlist.reorder; // 

var cur = linkedlist.first;
while (cur.next) {
  container.appendChild(cur)
  cur = cur.next;
}
document.removeChild(oldContainer);
document.appendChild(container);
// This is meant as pseudocode so forgive an errors in regards to the specifics
```

So my questions are the following:

1. Would this reduce browser reflows from n reflows to just 1 or 2 (where n is the number of divs)? If I understand it right, changing the z-index of a single element should cause either a browser repaint or a reflow.
2. Will the second approach work and stack elements in the order you append them?
3. Is there a way to move childs around using the DOM's child node structure already so I don't have to create a separate linked list? I only see removeChild and appendChild functions that I can use at the moment.

And yes performance is an issue since I'm planning on using this for graphics and html5 stuff. So where I can save I would like to save.

Comment: Welcome to SO. First of all nice question formatting but it's a bit too much to process I think... Maybe you could post a simpler example, with a demo at jsfiddle if possible.

Comment: I removed the comparison between the approaches since I can do that myself I just left in what I actually wanted to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well great it seems I've answered my own question after playing around with things and some research thanks to the good people at Opera. Pretty much yeah it's faster to perform updates on hidden/unseen elements on the browser, then to add it to the DOM tree. I got my confirmation from [here](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/efficient-javascript/). The actual trick is to set the hidden CSS tag, perform all the operations that affect display, then set hidden back to true and that reduces your browser reflows from O(n) to just 2 total.

Also this method for avoiding z-index certainly works. I unfortunately still haven't found a way to access the childNodes linked list for DOM elements. However, taking a closer look at the specification, it turns out that childNodes for DOM nodes is read-only, which likely means it's not possible unless there's some vague hack around it.